# My gnome3.14 dash has double icons for one app. How can I fix?

Tags: gnome, icons

I installed a new Gnome-14.10 and restored my own system (same version14.10) using `tar -xvzpf`
but since then, there are two identical icons for one app in the gnome dash:

[image: screenshot]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can install a menu editor to fix it

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

To edit the duplicated menu icon

Or you can just type

```
sudo -i 
nautilus -w /usr/share/applications
```

To see all the desktop files for menu items, and remove any duplicates, but it would be sensible to make a backup before changing any file.